# React bundle.js error syntax?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I have an error Uncaught ReferenceError: ReactDOM is not defined. I looked through developer tools firefox.

bundle.js  part of the code where the error is.

```
var React = __webpack_require__(1);
var ReactDom = __webpack_require__(158);

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(
  'h1',
  null,
  'Boilerplate app!'
), docucument.getElementById('app'));
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "boilerplate",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Simple Vova REact app",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "Vlad",
    "Hacki"
  ],
  "author": "\"MIT\"",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.5.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "webpack": "^1.12.13"
  }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code?

Comment: can you share your code?Have you added ReactDOM dependency in package.json?

Comment: you probably misstyped `ReactDOM` to `ReactDom` in import statement

Comment: @madox2 along with that, I think he also mistyped `document` to `docucument`

Comment: On my browser developer tool it says: ReactDOM is not defined. error points to this code:       ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(. When I run my server its empty does not show anything.

Comment: Thanks guys I'm new to react kinda dumb question I missed   docucument and reactDom error. It worked yesssssssss!